# XQuery: produce element with attr also with value?

Tags: xml, xquery

For example, I want to create such element below:

```
<book year="2010">Example name</book>
```

What is the correct usage of computed element constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
element book {
  attribute year { 2010 },
  'Example name'
}
```

Or some would suggest

```
element book {
  attribute year { 2010 },
  text { 'Example name' }
}
```